# RealURL: Remove Controller and Action from URL

Tags: typo3, extbase, realurl

I have an extension with a list and show action. Currently this extension can appear on multiple pages:

```
/page-1/
/page-2/subpage/
```

I have configured `realurl` like that:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
    'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
    'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        …
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'controller' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[controller]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
                ),
                'extension' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[action]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[controller]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[value]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'table',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'name',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted AND NOT hidden',
                            …
);

function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('page-1/', 'page-1/extension/', $params['URL']);
}

function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('page-1/extension/', 'page-1/', $params['URL']);
}
```

Now I get URLs like:

```
/page-1/ /* shows list */
/page-1/Action/show/name-of-single-element /* single view */
```

What I actually want is this:

```
/page-1/name-of-single-element /* single view */
```

How do I get rid of the action and controller?

If I remove:

```
array('GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[action]'),
array('GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[controller]'),
```

it appends the parameters to the URL.

Comment: It requires another approach, is it your extension ? can you change it's code? show me how do you build your links/urls

Comment: @biesior Yes, it's my own extension and yes, I can change everything. The links are build like this: `<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{article : article}" class="more" title="{article.name}">show article</f:link.action>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't avoid adding all the stuff when using `f:link.action` VH, instead you need to use `f:link.page` and pass only required params, sample:

```
<f:link.page additionalParams="{article : article.uid}" class="more" title="{article.name}">show article</f:link.page>
```

it will generate url like

```
/current/page/?article=123
```

or

```
/current/page/we-added-realurl-support-for-article
```

next in your first action of plugin (probably `list`) you just need to forward request to `show` action if given param exists:

```
public function listAction() {
    if (intval(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('article'))>0) $this->forward('show');

    // Rest of code for list action...
}
```

and probably change signature of `show`

```
public function showAction() {

    $article = $this->articleRepository->findByUid(intval(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('article')));

    if ($article == null) {
        $this->redirectToUri($this->uriBuilder->reset()->setTargetPageUid($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id)->build());
    }


    // Rest of code for show action...
}
```

Comment: +1 - works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I changed the code a bit to make it more versatile. I changed the signature to: `public function showAction(\namespace $article = null)` and wrapped the newly added part into this: `if (!$article) { … }`.

Comment: I am using an @transient property in my extension (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274477/parse-an-existing-json-string-in-fluid-template) - can it be that it fails with the above method? When I got it working, all that "transient" data wasn't output anymore

Comment: Seems that extbase was less strict towards the type of property (which I had set wrong) when using the "action" link than now with the alternative procedure. It had nothing to do with "transient"

Comment: That solution works really good. Thank you very much, in some cases it might be better to use the standard get variables like tx_yourext['article']

Comment: This answer is violating the aspects of domain-driven design and separation of concerns in may ways. Each action shall be called directly with the accordant and valid set of arguments - this is the job of the request-handler, not the job of any controller logic. By-passing the request/response separation and fetching GET parameters directly is another violation - and dangerous in terms of working with non-validated user submitted data (SQLi, XSS et al). Even if it works, it's still hacky...

Answer (score 7):

If the `URIbuilder` is used you can also use the configuration:

```
features.skipDefaultArguments = 1
```

for example;

```
# if enabled, default controller and/or action is skipped when creating URIs through the URI Builder 
plugin.tx_extension.features.skipDefaultArguments = 1
```

I use this configuration in combination with the realurl bypass

```
'postVarSets' => array(
  '_DEFAULT' => array(
    'extbaseParameters' => array(
      array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_plugin[action]',
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```