# In Extbase 6.2, don't use uid for list page

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

When using Extbase's "show" action:

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{event : event}">
```

I would like to look up said event by a special column ('customID').

The **actual TYPO3-uid** should NOT appear in the URL (with or without RealURL).

The reason is that the data has been imported, and the "real" uid is 'customId'.

There's always @biesior's approach using `f:link.page` https://stackoverflow.com/a/26145125/160968 – but I thought I'd try it with the official way.

(how) is it possible to do that in extbase/fluid?

Comment: My answer there is rather for avoiding Controller and Action parts in the URL, for just declaring the type of param in show action (other than model;s object) @lorenz has better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible. Let's assume your model Event has a property `customId`. So you generate your link like this:

`<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{event : event.customId}">`

The link generated will have a queryString like this:

`?tx_myext[event]=9999`

The showAction generated by the Extension Builder expects that the UID of the event is passed. The PropertyMapper then fetches the object automatically and assigns it to the view:

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \Your\Extension\Domain\Model\Event $event
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\Your\Extension\Domain\Model\Event $event) {
    $this->view->assign('event', $event);
}
```

But in your case you cannot fetch the object by UID because you passed the customId. So you need to fetch the object yourself:

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param integer $event
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction($event) {
    $event = $this->eventRepository->findOneByCustomId($event);
    $this->view->assign('event', $event);
}
```

The annotation `@param integer $event` tells TYPO3 that the parameter is "just" an integer. You then call the magic method `findOneByCustomId` from your eventRepository. `findOne` indicates that you want exactly one `Event` object back (and not a `QueryResult`), while the `ByCustomId` that queries an existing property of your `Event` model.

Comment: now I'm torn again. as this solution works as well as biesor's "clean-url" solution - what's the argument to stick with f:link.action instead of f:link.page again (if I only have a show and  list action)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with link.action vs. link.page. It just shows a way of requesting an object for a single view without using or exposing the uid. You still may go with the "clean URL" approach.

Comment: Yes, I was just not sure which was better. I guess it's only relevant if you have more than list/show actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use realUrl with lookUpTable? See here: https://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual#-.3ElookUpTable